# to convert dom document object to node type object

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-10.04, xmldom

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import xml.dom.minidom
from array import *
import re

count = array('i',[0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

def find_root_tags(file,str1,i):

    dom  = xml.dom.minidom.parse(file)

    if dom == str1:
        count[i] = count[i]+1

    for j in dom.getElementsByTagName(str1.lower()):    
        count[i] = count[i] + 1

    find_text(file,str1,i)
    find_root_attribute(file,str1,i,dom)


 def find_text(file,str1,i):

     str1 = str1.lower()
     exp = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
     with open(file) as f:
         lines = ''.join(line for line in f.readlines())
         text_only = exp.sub('',lines).strip()

     text_only = text_only.lower()
     k = text_only.count(str1)
     count[i] = count[i]+k


def find_root_attribute(file,str1,i,dom):

    str1 = str1.lower()
    for child in dom.childnodes:

         if child.hasAttributes():
             print cmn
```

when I run this code it gives me error that document object has no attribute `childnodes`. Basically I want to convert the document instance to node type instance and then want to use node attribute `childnodes`. Or should I again parse the `xml` file by creating an node instance. How can I do that ?

Please help, I'm new to `xml` parsing

Comment: Certainly it is possible to use dom and minidom - but this is the least preferred Python API for dealing with XML - try using elementtree instead - it is much, much easier: http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: I have used elementTree before but I was told that it is less efficient than DOM parsing so use Dom ? Is it true?

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. Try using lxml or beautiful soup for your needs. I tried refactoring your code, but since you havent documented you methods, I dont know what they do exactly or what do the arguments str1, i mean.

Comment: The recomendation of Python developers is to use Etree - there is a C imlementation of it called cElementTree that should be faster - use: from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET . (the recomendations and "unhiding" of cElementTree are taken care of fro Python 3.3 - but it is available for Python 2.7 (and possibly earlier))